# Comments with jsf ui:insert

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-1.2

I want to put this comment into the  :

```
<head>
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"> 
    </script>
  <![endif]-->
  <ui:insert name="faceletHeader"/>
</head>
```

but comment will be removed from head. There is no setted skip comment value in config files.
How to insert this comment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<h:outputText escape="false">`

```html
<h:outputText value="&lt;!--[if lt IE 8]&gt;&lt;script src=&quot;http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt;" escape="false" />
```